# Mild solution of abstract Cauchy problem.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators, cauchy-problem

I am dealing with the following Cauchy problem on $[0,T]\times \mathbb R$

\begin{cases}
\partial_t u= \partial_x u+F(u(t)), \\
u(0,x)=\varphi(x)
\end{cases}
where $F$ is some Lipschitz continuous function, there are some local-existence results for this kind of problem.

I would like to write down the mild solution for this problem, so first thing I wrote this as an abstract Cauchy problem  on some Banach space ($\star$)
\begin{cases}
 u'(t)= A u(t)+F(u(t)), \\
u(0,x)=\varphi(x)
\end{cases}

Then assuming that $A$ is the generator of a $C_0$-semigroup $(T(t))$ then the mild solution will be given by ($\star$)

$$u(t)=T(t)\varphi(x)+\int_0^t T(t-s)F(u(s))ds$$

---

### Questions:

(1) When I write down my Cauchy problem in abstract form, which Banach space should I consider? Since $A$ is a differential operator I believe I should take $C^1$ or a Sobolev space $W^{1,1}$.

(2) $A$ is the infinitesimal generator of the translation semigroup, but is it a $C_0$-semigroup? Can we write a mild solution even if $A$ is not the generator of a $C_0$-semigroup? (namely if it is the generator of some semigroup with less regularity).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In most cases it is helpful to consider $L^2$ as Banach space, because it is also a Hilbert space and has additional structure which becomes handy to justify hat $A$ is generator. Moreover, in most applications the energy of the system that is described by the PDE has a quadratic energy function which gives an equivalent norm to the $L^2$ norm. However, there are cases where it is more adequate to use another space. The Sobolev space will also appear, but as the domain of your operator $A$.
In your particular example you need additional boundary conditions for $A$ to be a generator.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek thanks for your comment! I have another very simple question, if there's a classic solution for the pde, then is $u(t)=\varphi(x+t)+\int_0^t F(u(s,x+(t-s)))ds$ a mild solution for the pde? If I differentiate the expression above wrt to time I obtain 
$u_t'(t,x)=\varphi'(x+t)+F(u(t,x))$

Comment: I guess this depends on the semigroup $A$ and the function $F$ as this can be regarded as non linear feedback. Maybe you can find something for non linear feedback.